# Modifying WP URL handing code?

Tags: php, wp-query, url-rewriting, urls, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use mod_rewrite and modify WordPress' URL handling to allow for passing variables to PHP from the URL while maintaining "pretty permalink" functionality.  (on WP 3.2.1)

Something like this:

http:/epiclasers.com/hello-world
(normal with permalinks set to /%postname%)

http:/epiclasers.com/state/hello-world
(WP should display the same hello-world post as above, but also would pass the state string to PHP as a variable)

http:/epiclasers.com/state/city/hello-world
(WP should display the hello-world post, but would pass the state and city strings to PHP as variables)

I added the following mod_rewrite directives to my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/ /index.php?state=$1&city=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/ /index.php?state=$1 [L]
```

which kind of works.  The variables are being passed, and PHP can grab them with:

> $state = $_GET['state'];
>   $city = $_GET['city'];

The problem is that WP is getting confused by the variables in the URL and isn't outputting the correct template file.  URL's like these:

http://epiclasers.com/arizona/phoenix/
http:/epiclasers.com/arizona/phoenix/hello-world
http://epiclasers.com/arizona/

are bringing up the 404 page not found template.

How do I modify the WP URL handling code to ignore the /state and /city parts of the URL without also breaking URLs like:

http:/epiclasers.com/category/category1
http:/epiclasers.com/tag/tag1
http:/epiclasers.com/category/category2/subcategory

etc.

Thanks,
Devin

Comment: Can't you just add a rule earlier for the tag|category (and so on) that you need? You also have the option to do some filtering based on the permalink URL. It's post_rewrite_rule. Checkout https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure how what you are suggesting will fix the problems I am having.  I also don't have any experience with modifying WP code in this way, unfortunately.  I'm really needing some specific help here.

Comment: I was thinking about adding a rule above your rule for e.g. tag, category. Sorry that I can't provide exact rule so you need to try for yourself or hope for answer. Something like RerwriteRule ^(tag|category) index.php [L]

Comment: The mod_rewrite directives don't seem to be the problem.  The problem seems to be that WordPress is ignoring the mod_rewrite output and processing the request/query based on $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this with a little bit of code (in the form of a plugin):

```
if(isset($_GET['state']) OR isset($_GET['city'])) {
$url = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$url = end($url);
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = "/" . $url;
}
```

This code in essence removes the "/arizona/" or "/arizona/phoenix/" from the REQUEST_URI global variable and replaces it with "/", which then forces WP to serve up the front page template using index.php. Fixed!

Perhaps a few of you can vote this answer up for me. :)